# How we will pass drop down value as argument with ajax call back function in drupal 7?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

i want to pass drop down value in ajax-callback function as argument ($user_id,$selected) onchange but i am not getting $selected value in this ajax-callback function onchange event**

Comment: are you using drupal ajax framework? or implemented custom jquery on client side?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery: `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();`

Comment: sir in drupal 7 this is not working.i want to know how to pass argument with call back function $form['changethis'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Rece/Paid'),
    '#description' => t('See Records'),
 '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => $selected,
 '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
 'event' => 'change',
    'progress' => array(
    'type' => 'none',
      ),
    ),
 
  );

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['changethis'] = array( 
'#type' => 'select', 
'#title' => t('Rece/Paid'), 
'#description' => t('See Records'), 
'#options' => $options, 
'#default_value' => $selected, 
'#ajax' => array( 
  'callback' => 'ajax_callback', 
  'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div', 
  'event' => 'change', 
  'progress' => array( 'type' => 'none', ),
 ), 
);
```

Above added for readability.

Is your select posting something and not getting a result? Or is it not posting anything at all?

Your code looks ok, but are you sure you want ajax callback 'ajax_callback'? Shouldn't this be your own function that returns part of the form?

Also, I'm not sure about `'progress' => array( 'type' => 'none', ),` The documentation says only 'throbber' and 'bar' are valid.

**Try something like this instead**

```
function my_module_create_form($form, $form_state){

  // check form_state here to see if the form has been submitted
  // via ajax and change if needed.

  $options = array(0, 1, 2);
  $selected = 0;

  $form = array();
  $form['changethis'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'select', 
  '#title' => t('Rece/Paid'), 
  '#description' => t('See Records'), 
  '#options' => $options, 
  '#default_value' => $selected, 
  '#ajax' => array( 
    'callback' => 'my_module_ajax_callback', 
    'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div', 
    'event' => 'change', 
   ), 
  );
  return $form;
}

function my_module_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {

  // because this is called from change event on select, 
  // it wont rebuild the form (call my_module_create_form).
  // If you want it to you have to set $form_state['rebuild']
  // (or it may be $form['rebuild'], I can't remember which one.)      

  // return form part
  return $form['changethis'];
}
```

Comment: actually i want to pass drop down value onchange event to ajax_callback() function as parameter.but i dont know how i will get that value and how i will pass that value within this function

Comment: I updated the original answer to force it to call the ajax on change event, though I think this is the default for select type.

Comment: it is all outlined in the drupal form api documentation. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

Comment: the 'event' => 'change' is what makes the ajax get called on change event.